# Pass complex data from form submit?

Tags: c#, forms, knockout.js

I have a array of objects that each have like 5 fields  and I want to send that array on a form submit. But I keep getting null and not sure what im doing wrong.

```
<form method="post" ....>
<table>
<!-- ko foreach: items-->
<tr>
   <td>
      <span data-bind="text: Category"></span>
      <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:ko.toJSON($data)" />
   </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
</table>
</form>


 [HttpPost]
 public void MyItems(List<Item> data)
 {

 }
```

Item matches the JSON of the javascript object.

How can I get my array of items to my C# call?

Comment: Your input doesn't have a name... And submitting JSON is an all or nothing kind of thing,not JSON encoded parameters using traditional POST/GET.

Comment: Could you include the ... after the form method="post"?

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize a listitem into string as a parameter in javascript, and deserialize it in the action mvc.

```
<form method="post" ....>
<table>
<!-- ko foreach: items-->
<tr>
   <td>
      <span data-bind="text: Category"></span>
      <input type="hidden" value="ko.toJSON($data)" />
   </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
</table>
</form>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void MyItems(string data)
 {
    JavaScriptSerializer parser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var info = parser.Deserialize<List<Item>>(data);
 }
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work. I get a 404 error - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your submit of the JSON array in a variable like "items", it is important the variable names match. ASP.NET will automatically deserialize the JSON into your object, no need to do it manually. I've fully tested this and do it often so I know it works.

```
[HttpPost]
// Note how the argument name is "items"
 public ActionResult MyItems(List<Item> items)
 {
     // set a breakpoint and check the items List
     return Content("success")
 }

public class Item
{
// Make sure to use public properties get/set
    public string Category {get;set;}
}
```

And your javascript

```
function Item()
{
    this.Category = ko.observable();
}

function ViewModel()
{
    this.Items = ko.observableArray();

    this.submit = function() {
        // note how we make sure argument name matches "items" as in Controller
        var myData = ko.toJSON(  { items: this.Items() });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/MyItems',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: myData,
            success: function(data){
                // check result
            }
        })

    }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

var item1 = new Item();
item1.Category("Cat1");
vm.Items.push(item1);

vm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're posting an html form and not `JSON`, you're going to need to get into the raw form posted data to get your `JSON` string out. Typically this is done with `Request.Form`? It looks like what your missing is your `name` attribute on your hidden tag. Once you have that in place it should be as simple as this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyHiddenElement" data-bind="value:ko.toJSON($data)" />

string json = Request.Form["MyHiddenElement"];
```

One thing that also might be helpful  is that if you throw down a number of hidden tags and give them all the same name, you can do a Request.Form of the given name, and you will get back a comma delimited array list of the `<Input` hidden values. This is very useful for complex data posting scenarios.

```
<input type='hidden' name="MyHiddenElement" value="1" />
<input type='hidden' name="MyHiddenElement" value="2" />
<input type='hidden' name="MyHiddenElement" value="3" />

string csvList = Request.Form["MyHiddenElement"];
```